# Difference between pleasure and delight

Tags: difference

I didn't find anything very clear. What is the exactly difference between "pleasure" and "delight"?

Comment: Delight is *great* pleasure.

Comment: I'm only guessing,but what I'm guessing is that the down-vote is because this could have been answered with a simple dictionary search.

Comment: @puppetsock No, it's not because according to wordreference.com delight: means also pleasure and enjoy, and if you look at pleasure in the same website, it means: enjoyment. So It's not clear, at least for me, a leaner. Some website said that there is not very difference between them, but I'm not sure about that definition, thus I created a new answer (after searching if the same question was already proposed here) and I was hoping for clarification answers, instead useless downvotes and simple answer (that I'm able to find it too) since I'm also a new user here,I was expecting more politeness

Comment: This is indeed answerable by a dictionary look-up. See e.g. https://www.lexico.com/definition/delight or https://www.thefreedictionary.com/Delight or https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/delight. In total, 5 dictionaries, and they all define the word similarly. Furthermore, I think you're overreacting. No one has been impolite to you; in fact, you're the one showing impertinence. You're not very new either and you should know you're required to show the results of your research when asking your question. Find the relevant help pages in the menu at the top.

Comment: @userr2684291 I replied in that manner because after 10 minutes I had already 1 downvote, and since I am a newbie here and also a learner of English language, I would have expected more comprehension for a simple question, asked politely. Have a nice day.

Comment: "I'm guessing is that the down-vote is because this could have been answered with a simple dictionary search" You guess right.

Answer (score 0):

According to a little research I did, I can deduce that, the difference between "delight" and "pleasure" is not very big.

Pleasure can be defined as a positive sensation that is generated from **satisfying some need**, such as a drink for thirst, food for hunger, rest for fatigue.

Delight is a satisfaction to the spirit and the senses, it is to feel sensual fullness (**that is to say of the senses**), it is quite associated with art, the culinary field or even as a personal value.

I hope this helps you.

Comment: So, the meaning of the two words is more or less the same (generally) but their usage is different?

Comment: You are correct, the meaning of both words is similar, but the context in which it is used is different.

Comment: As has been said, delight is **great** pleasure, while pleasure, described thus, can be any degree between slight and great. I would call Daniela F's answer somewhat misleading.

Answer (score 0):

The difference is one of degree. Pleasure can be slight or great; delight is restricted to great pleasure.

> Meaning of pleasure in English
>
> pleasure noun [ C or U ]
>
> enjoyment, happiness, or satisfaction, or something that gives this

[Pleasure (Cambridge Dictionary](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/pleasure)

> Meaning of delight in English
>
> delight noun [ C or U ]
>
> (something or someone that gives) **great** pleasure, satisfaction, or happiness

[Delight (Cambridge Dictionary)](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/delight)

Answer (score 0):

**"Delight"** is a higher degree of pleasure thus brings more pleasure and satisfaction.

- *This song is **pleasant**.* - Good and satisfying, nice to the ear.
- *This song is **delightful**.* - Very good. It brings me much pleasure to listen to it.

However, there are set phrases which use the word **"pleasure"** only, i.e.:

- **It's a pleasure to meet you.** - is used when we have the pleasure or the delight of meeting someone. But you can say: I am **pleased/delighted** to meet you. There are various additions you can imbue into this phrase, like: *It is a great pleasure to finally meet you.*
- **My pleasure!** - means *"You're welcome!"*, *"No problem!"* and the likes of these.

And idioms:

- **What's your pleasure?** *(informal)* - used to ask what drink someone would like to be served.

Answer (score 0):

"Pleasure" can be seen as the sensation of being pleased, that is, feeling satisfaction or relief when a consciously felt lack is satisfied by conscious action. When I'm hungry, or just craving, and I eat, I feel pleasure.
"Delight" has an element of surprise. It isn't expected, and it didn't happen because I deliberately tried to bring it about. If it's the result of my conscious effort, it's mere pleasure.

Answer (score -1):

Delight usually connotes simple joy, and may be associated with surprise or novelty.

> The little girl's face lit up in delight when she saw the giant lollipop.
>
> I admit, this silly, heartwarming movie always brings me the same delight, no matter how many times I see it.

Pleasure suggests an enjoyment of not just viewing something, but interacting with and being stimulated by it. The emotions it describes may be subtler or more complex.

> As the sun warmed her cold skin, her shoulders relaxed and her face scrunched up with pleasure.
>
> I always find pleasure in a healthy debate with someone who has well-researched opinions and an open mind.

Both are of course used in polite stock phrases, without any of the above connotations.

> A: Delighted to meet you.
>
> B: Yes, a pleasure.